# MySQL ORDER BY two clauses (descending and ascending)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have this table:

```sql
create table products(name text, quantity int);
insert into products values ("A", 10);
insert into products values ("B", 0);
insert into products values ("C", 15);
insert into products values ("D", 0);
insert into products values ("E", 17);
```

I would like to order by product name, but keep products with `quantity = 0` at the bottom, like this:

```
name    quantity
A       10
C       15
E       17
B       0
D       0
```

I've tried:
`select * from products order by quantity desc, name asc;` but it but while it correctly keeps `quantity = 0` at the bottom, name ordering is reversed. Is `ORDER BY` even the right thing to use in this case?

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6985a4/1/0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use:

```
order by (quantity = 0), name
```

Boolean values are ordered with "false" first then "true".

I would use this to be explicit, rather than using a special value such as `'z'` -- which won't even work if you have names that start with `'z'`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select * from products 
order by case when quantity = 0 then "z" else name end asc;
```

Comment: . . This won't work if you want names that start with `z`, such as `'zip'`.

Comment: good point GL, like the way you used my handle to prove it :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
select name, quantity from products WHERE quantity>0 order by name) t1
UNION
select name, quantity from products t2 WHERE quantity<=0;
```

Comment: What kind of error it will return? Check it on the site that author provided - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6985a4/1/0 , and everything working just fine.

Comment: you have an "order by" before union. the sqlfiddle you've sent, there is no "union" keyword used.